# IE-8 Flash fallback working offline but not online

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video, video.js

For some unknown reason under IE-8 the flash fallback only works when running the site/page from the local file system (file://). When running online(htttp://) from an IIS server with mime types configured for MP4 the video won't load in IE-8. Chrome does however load the video correctly both offline and online.

Flash fallback error: "FLASH: srcnotfound" is shown onscreen.

The video src is dynamically populated via javascript after the page has loaded and repopulated with a different src after a different video is clicked. I've verified via chrome and offline that the video src (which is a relative path) is accurate.

**HTML**

```
<video id="Video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="1010" height="568.125">
<source src="" type='video/mp4' />
<p class="vjs-no-js">Please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

**Javascript**

```
function LoadVideo(vidSrc){
    //Initialize Video.js library
    videojs("Video1", {"autoplay":true}, function(){
        this.src([{type: "video/mp4", src: vidSrc}]);
        this.play();
    });
}
```

Comment: That's odd. Any chance you could put up a jsbin with the example? http://jsbin.com/axedog/edit It could be a security error of some sort.

Comment: I can't explain why or what, but after toggling the Browser Mode from IE8 to IE8 compatibility and back to IE8 again it now works.

Comment: Ha, well, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 and later using an emulation mode of IE8 and lower (compatibility view) will ignore <video> tags.

To provide flash fallback, nest object inside your video tags.

<video>

<object>
Your useragent does not support common video formats.
</object>

</video>

additionally userAgents can disable flash content... ActiveX filtering, no-flash addons for webkit and gecko... etc...

Comment: Thanks for causing me to toggle the browser mode back and forth as simply toggling from IE-8 to IE-8 compatibility mode and back again it "magically" fixed it.